# Migrating data from Solr 1.4 to 4.10 through 3.5 Index issue

Tags: tomcat, solr, solr4

I'm trying to upgrade from Solr 1.4 to Solr 4.10 using Solr 3.5 as an intermediate state between the two major versions. The data set I migrate is, I think, very large, i.e the data folder size is more than 13 GB. Migrating from 1.4 to 3.5 has been occurred successfully. I have copied the data folder of the collection and also copied the conf folder from Solr 3.5 to Solr 4.10. However, I got the following error:

> ** ERROR  CoreContainer  Error creating core [newsarchive]: Error opening new searcher**

And the detailed log data is:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:873)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:646)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:491)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:249)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1565)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1677)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:845)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooOldException: Format version is not supported (resource: MMapIndexInput(path="C:\news\data\newsarchive\index\_4p.fdx")): 1 (needs to be between 2 and 3). This version of Lucene only supports indexes created with release 3.0 and later.
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene3x.Lucene3xStoredFieldsReader.checkCodeVersion(Lucene3xStoredFieldsReader.java:121)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene3x.Lucene3xSegmentInfoReader.readLegacyInfos(Lucene3xSegmentInfoReader.java:75)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:418)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$1.doBody(SegmentInfos.java:458)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:913)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:759)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:454)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:794)
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.<init>(SolrIndexWriter.java:77)
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.create(SolrIndexWriter.java:64)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.createMainIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:279)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.getIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:111)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1528)
    ... 10 more
```

Also, I find the following Error at the end after the error above in the log:

**

> ERROR SolrIndexWriter SolrIndexWriter was not closed prior to
>   finalize(),​ indicates a bug -- POSSIBLE RESOURCE LEAK!!!

And

> ERROR SolrIndexWriter Error closing IndexWriter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Solr opens an old index, it does as little work as possible to update it. Generally this means that old segments are *not* rewritten in a new format until they're merged. This saves a lot of I/O, and people with large indexes probably don't want to rewrite their entire index every time the index format changes slightly. However, it means that you have to do a little extra work to migrate an index from old (>1 major version behind) versions of Solr. The recommended procedure is to use `org.apache.lucene.index.IndexUpgrader` to upgrade the index without merging. Easiest thing would be to grab lucene-core 3.5 [from Maven](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.lucene%7Clucene-core%7C3.5.0%7Cjar) and run `java -cp lucene-core.jar org.apache.lucene.index.IndexUpgrader [-delete-prior-commits] [-verbose] indexDir`, then repeat with [lucene-core 4.10](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.lucene%7Clucene-core%7C4.10.4%7Cjar).

Comment: Indeed, I tried the command you have regarded from the CMD and I have got this error:  `Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.lucene.index.IndexUpgrader`

Comment: Thank you very much, it is `java -cp lucene-core.jar org.apache.lucene.index.IndexUpgrader [-delete-prior-commits] [-verbose] indexDir` However, I just used it in the wrong place i.e `C:\ ` However, I should use it where lucene-core-3.5.0.jar is found. Generally, it should found in the Tomcat directory under `webapps\solr\WEB-INF\lib`